# Reporting Services RDLC Table Page Breaks within a Cell with a SubReport

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, subreport, page-break

I am having a paging issue with my RLDC report that has a SubReport. The report has a table that prints the header data, then has a SubReport that I placed in a detail cell row within the table to print several detail lines that relate to the header data.

This works as I want. However, the SubReport can span more than one page and this can lead to my problem. When the page is 2/3 full (or even less than 1/4 full) and the SubReport has enough items in it to cause it to go to a second page, the SubReport will then print on the next page. I would rather have it fill out the rest of the page before wrapping to new page.

I have searched all of the options to see if I could figure this out. Is there a setting I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known BUG.  See the following article:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a68d06f4-2612-47ad-9f07-6d5753315c36/

Comment: Thank you! I must not have been using the right keywords to find this. Now to try something else...